# Automapper: DTO with Array to List

Tags: c#, automapper

I know the basics of Automapper but I was wondering if it can also do more complex things or if I am forced to do things like that manually. Let me explain it with my current scenario.

**OrderStatusDTO**

```
public class OrderStatusDTO
{
    [Required]
    public int[] OrderIds { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

The purpose of this DTO is fairly simple; it creates an order status for multiple orders at the same time.

**OrderStatus**

```
public class OrderStatus
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

This is the database entity. `StatusId`, `Username`, `Comment` and `Date` will be the same for all of them and there should be as many OrderStatus objects as the size of the `OrderStatusDTO.OrderIds` array. Each object's `OrderId` property will match with one of the values of the `OrderStatusDTO.OrderIds` array.

Is it possible to use Automapper for this, such that I could to something like this as the final result:

```
_mapper.Map<OrderStatusDTO, List<OrderStatus>>(orderStatusDTO);
```

**Edit**:

In a loop, it would look like the following.

```
List<OrderStatus> orderStatus = new List<OrderStatus>();
for (int i = 0; i < orderStatusDTO.OrderIds.Length; i++) {
    OrderStatus orderStatus = new OrderStatus();
    orderStatus.OrderId = orderStatusDTO.OrderIds[i];
    orderStatus.StatusId = orderStatusDTO.StatusId;
    orderStatus.Username = orderStatusDTO.Username;
    orderStatus.Comment = orderStatusDTO.Comment;
    orderStatus.Date = orderStatusDTO.Date;
    orderStatus.Add(orderStatus);
}
```

Comment: I like your idea, but I dont think Automapper supports this.
Look at the [documentation](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Lists-and-arrays.html), search for `To be specific, the source collection types supported include:`

Answer (score -1):

You have to provide `automapper` configuration like this -

```
cfg.CreateMap<OrderStatusDTO, List<OrderStatus>>()
                    .ConvertUsing<OrderStatusDTOConverter>();
```

Where, `OrderStatusDTOConverter` is defined as -

```
    public class OrderStatusDTOConverter : ITypeConverter<OrderStatusDTO, List<OrderStatus>>
    {
        public List<OrderStatus> Convert(OrderStatusDTO source, List<OrderStatus> destination, ResolutionContext context)
        {
            var list = new List<OrderStatus>();
            foreach (var orderId in source.OrderIds)
            {
                list.Add(new OrderStatus
                {
                    Comment = source.Comment,
                    Date = source.Date,
                    OrderId = orderId,
                    StatusId = source.StatusId,
                    Username = source.Username
                });
            }
            return list;
        }
    }
```

Now `Map` as -

```
var orderList = mapper.Map<List<OrderStatus>>(orderDTO);
```

And if you want reverse as well, Add configuration as  -

```
cfg.CreateMap<List<OrderStatus>, OrderStatusDTO>()
                .ForMember(p => p.OrderIds, opts => opts.MapFrom(s => s.Select(r => r.OrderId).ToArray()))
                .ForMember(p => p.StatusId, opts => opts.MapFrom(s => s.Any() ? s.FirstOrDefault().StatusId : 0))
                .ForMember(p => p.Username, opts => opts.MapFrom(s => s.Any() ? s.FirstOrDefault().Username : string.Empty))
                .ForMember(p => p.Date, opts => opts.MapFrom(s => s.Any() ? s.FirstOrDefault().Date : new DateTime()))
                .ForMember(p => p.Comment, opts => opts.MapFrom(s => s.Any() ? s.FirstOrDefault().Username : string.Empty));
```